# Whats wrong with my MYSQL QUERY?

Tags: mysql

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my query.
I am trying to fetch data fro my table based on the column called weekend, if weekend is set to "0" show from Sunday 6pm until Friday 9pm, then if weekend is set to "1" Show from Friday 9pm until Sunday 6pm.

```
SELECT * 
FROM closures 
WHERE closures.weekend = 0 
      OR WEEKDAY(NOW()) < 4 
      AND closures.weekend = 1 
      OR WEEKDAY(NOW()) > 4 
      OR (WEEKDAY(NOW())=4 AND HOUR(NOW())>21) 
      OR (WEEKDAY(NOW())=6 AND HOUR(NOW())<18)
```

Comment: Has the formatting cut your code off or is there really no 'select' in that statement?

Comment: You are missing the SELECT part :)

Comment: With so many OR clauses, you will be needing more `()` groups or you'll get most or all rows on every query.

Comment: What do you mean by "show Friday 9pm until Sunday 6pm" ?  That makes no sense without the context of what's actually in the `closures` table.

Comment: What I mean is the database results that are brought back should be depending on the day and time of the week.

Comment: so are those fields in the database?

Comment: the only field that it should be depending on weather its "1 or 0" is the column called weekend

Comment: OK, so AIUI what you mean is that _when the current time is in the ranges specified, only show those records that have `weekend = 0`, otherwise show those with `weekend = 1`_ ?  That's kinda the opposite sense to what you described.

Comment: the field in question is weekend..thats in the table. So what I want is to get the day & time from the db server and use it to determine what rows to fetch from the value of  "1 or 0" in the weekend column.

Comment: Im sorry for the confusion..i am totally new to mysql...But yes Alnitak you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

It helps to phrase the question properly.  What you should have said is *"between 9pm Friday and 6pm Sunday I want to show the rows where `closures.weekend = 1`, otherwise show those where `closures.weekend = 0`"*.

Hence what you need to do is generate a value of `1` or `0` depending on whether it's the weekend or not, and then `SELECT` those rows where `weekend` has that value, i.e:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    closures
WHERE
    weekend = IF(
         (WEEKDAY(NOW()) = 4 AND HOUR(NOW()) >= 21)
      OR (WEEKDAY(NOW()) = 5)
      OR (WEEKDAY(NOW()) = 6 AND HOUR(NOW()) < 18)
    , 1, 0)
```

Comment: when i query that it gives me this error:
Invalid query: Unknown column 'NOW' in 'where clause'

Comment: @user1221373 I had a typo - it's fixed (and tested) now

Comment: Thank you very much! yes it works. Now i think its time for me to pick up a book on MYSQL. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Weekend cant be both, 0 and 1

```
SELECT *
FROM
  closures
WHERE

  closures.weekend = 0
  OR 
  ( 
  WEEKDAY(NOW()) < 4
  AND closures.weekend = 1
  )
  OR WEEKDAY(NOW()) > 4
  OR
(WEEKDAY(NOW())=4 AND HOUR(NOW())>21)
OR
(WEEKDAY(NOW())=6 AND HOUR(NOW())<18)
```

Comment: your additional brackets haven't changed the operator precedence.

Comment: so if i switch the AND from weekends to OR , it should work? Soory for the lack of knowledge, i am very new to mysql.

Comment: to be honest, im not quite sure what he is trying to accomplish :)

Comment: @Rufinus indeed, the question makes little sense without some sample data from the table.

Comment: ok...some background. I have a google map that reads from my db. I want to show certain markers on the map depending on the time & day.

Comment: here is the link to the php file that is writing the xml
http://d4fdot.com/google/phpsqlajax_genxml2.php

Answer (score -2):

My first guess is that the

SELECT field1, field2, ...

is missing ?

Comment: this is what I have exactly:

"SELECT *
FROM
  closures
WHERE
  closures.weekend = 0
  OR WEEKDAY(NOW()) < 4
  AND closures.weekend = 1
  OR WEEKDAY(NOW()) > 4
  OR
(WEEKDAY(NOW())=4 AND HOUR(NOW())>21)
OR
(WEEKDAY(NOW())=6 AND HOUR(NOW())<18)
"